# Tinyxml2 error while parsing a xml file with c++

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml2

I'm using tinyxml2 to parse a xml file. While debugging with some prints:

```
XMLDocument doc;  
doc.LoadFile("../../Demos/config.xml");
std::cout << "file loaded" << std::endl;

XMLNode * pRoot = doc.FirstChild();
std::cout << "first element loadaed" << std::endl;
if (pRoot == nullptr) std::cout << "oops" << std::endl;
```

I noticed my program would print the last `std::cout` and then would give  segmentation fault error. My problem is I don't get it why the `pRoot` is `null`. The xml file I'm giving my program is the following:

```
<scene>
    <group>
        <translate X="5" Y="0" Z="2" />
        <rotate angle="45" axisX="0" axisY="1" axisZ="0" />
        <models>
            <model file=”sphere.3d” />
        </models>
    </group>
</scene>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of `LoadFile`. Does `LoadFile` return `XML_SUCCESS`? Otherwise the file might not even be loaded. Are you searching in the right folder?

Comment: the file is indeed not being loaded correctly, even though i have no idea why. The path is absolutely correct.

Comment: i've tried putting the file in my desktop and just giving the absolute path and it just gives the same error. I have no idea why

Comment: Which error does it return? Check the value returned by LoadFile.

Comment: idk what error it returns.
i've noticed on the doc, it says that "TinyXML-2 doesn't parse or use DTDs (Document Type Definitions) or XSLs (eXtensible Stylesheet Language.)"
i don't know what DTD or XSL are, but could this be the case?

Comment: ``doc.LoadFile("../../Demos/config.xml")`` returns a value, but you're not checking it. change the line to ``XMLError res = doc.LoadFile("../../Demos/config.xml");`` to see the actual error.